# Which Broom Company Makes the Firebolt?

Tags: harry-potter

**Which broom company makes the Firebolt?**

> THE FIREBOLT: *This state-of-the-art racing broom sports a streamlined, superfine handle of ash, treated with a diamond-hard polish and hand-numbered with its own registration number. Each individually selected birch twig in the broomtail has been honed to aerodynamic perfection, giving the Firebolt unsurpassable balance and pinpoint precision. The Firebolt has an acceleration of 0–150 miles an hour in ten seconds and incorporates an unbreakable braking charm. Price on request.*
>   <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 43 - Bloomsbury - chapter 4, *The Leaky Cauldron*</sub>

According to *Quidditch Through the Ages*, the Nimbus Racing Broom Company has been the top racing broom manufacturer basically since the company opened in 1967, but *QTTA* makes no mention of whether Nimbus manufactured the Firebolt.

**Is the Firebolt a Nimbus broom or is it manufactured by another broom company?**

★ An answer from canon, any J.K. Rowling interviews, or Pottermore would be great!

Comment: Figures that Ferrari has a wizardry department.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Firebolt was first developed by Randolph Spudmore around 1993.

This is quoted from http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Firebolt

Don't know how cannon it is,but it does say it's based on one of Pottermores latest updates.There is nothing about manufacturer though,but the content insinuates that Nimbus was not the manufacturer.

Ok I quick google for Randoplh Spudmore reveals he was the son of Able Spudmore of Ellerby and Spudmore a Black Forest broomstick manufacturing company.Though it only says they released the Tinderblast and the Swiftstick.Nothing explicitly says they released the Firebolt though.

Comment: This is a good lead! I'll have to check it out on Pottermore to verify it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad it helped :D

Comment: Verified! +1 and accept. :)

Answer (score 0):

As quoted in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broomsticks_in_Harry_Potter#Broomsticks)

> The Firebolt remains the fastest broom in the world, having surpassed the previous record holder, the Nimbus 2001 (which Draco Malfoy owns), and its price is so high it is only available upon request.

So seems it is a custom made broomstick rather than one of a brand.

Comment: If it's custom why is it standard for the Quidditch World Cup? And that still doesn't answer who manufactures it.

Comment: That wording is consistent with it being a model of broom that can be purchased commercially. Being referred to in the singular doesn't mean there's only one. People refer to products (like cars) in this way all the time.

Comment: I think the broom can be purchased commercially.  The "available on request" refers to the price: in Prisoner the students admire a Firebolt in a shop window in Diagon Alley where instead of a figure, "price available on request" is written.

Comment: I never really thought about it until i read this question. As far as i know, it was never stated who made the firebolt. I always just assumed it was made by a group of expert broommakers. For all we know it was made by the Firebolt Company, or someone called Firebolt. Maybe it's made by Quality Quidditch Supplies, the shop where harry first seen it.

Comment: I don't *think* I've ever read in canon that the Nimbus 2001 was a record-holder in any capacity, although it makes sense that it would be an improvement on the Nimbus 2000. Can you point me to this info in the books? I don't think you've answered the question. The Wiki material in your answer isn't sourced from canon; the answer quotes material that I have already included in the original question; and the idea of the Firebolt being custom-made, while certainly plausible, is only speculative :/ I think your answer would make a great comment, though.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting an ambiguous pronoun - "its price is so high ***it*** is only available on request" - I believe the "it" here refers to the broom's price, not the broom itself, so this quote does  not suggest the broom is custom made.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - Louisville Sluggers are pretty much standard in MLB, yet they are also custom manufactured for various players.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebolt was developed in secret, and is still made is small quantities. http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Firebolt

Comment: Hello and welcome to sf+f.stackexchange.  Unfortunately this answer doesn't answer the question which asks for a canon reference as to which company makes the Firebolt.  While offsite links to other sites are good to back up your answers, we tend not to include all the information within the answer here, because web sites come and go, and we aim to be a helpful reference without the need to visit external sites.  Thanks for contributing and I hope you enjoy using the site.